# Powershell Out-File changing characters it shouldn't

Tags: powershell, utf-8

I am trying to modify an InstallShield ism file (which is encoded at utf-8, however even if I use Encoding utf8, the encoding stays the same but the files
" ' " become " â€™ ", read that as commas become those characters.

I am doing the following to manipulate the ProductCode:

```
$guid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid();
$childItem = Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:ismlocation\reports\Reports.ism";
(Get-Content -Path $childItem) -replace "ProductCode</td><td>{[-0-9a-zA-Z]*}</td>","ProductCode</td><td>{$guid}</td>" | Out-File -Encoding utf8 -FilePath $childItem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to modify encoding when you load your datas :

```
Get-Content -Path $childItem -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to expound on the code in your answer. Tell about how it works or what exactly you are doing. This helps newer developers understand exactly what is going on.

Comment: thank you, I found this about 10 seconds before I saw this. I didn't realize you also need to read it the same way.